# Apache Permission issue

Tags: apache-2.2, troubleshooting, filesystems, upload, permissions

How do I resolve an issue of permissions in apache. The initial task that I am trying to get working is to upload a mura plugin the the temp directory of ColdFusion9. However, I have since discovered that this issue isn't a ColdFusion issue.

ColdFusion is running as the apache user:

```
# ps aux | grep coldfusion
apache   31016  0.0  0.0   2104   664 ?    S    Oct27   0:00 /opt/coldfusion9 ...
apache   31017  0.7 24.5 933260 513976 ?   Sl   Oct27  18:02 /opt/coldfusion9 ...
```

Apache has access to the directory that I'm attempting to write to:

```
# namei -m /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/
f: /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/
 drwxr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x opt
 drwxrwxrwx coldfusion9
 drwxrwxr-x runtime
 drwxrwxr-x servers
 drwxr-xr-x coldfusion
 drwxr-xr-x SERVER-INF
 drwxr-xr-x temp
 drwxr-xr-x wwwroot-tmp

# ls -la /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Oct 28 15:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache root   4096 Oct 27 21:33 ..
```

There are no extended attributes assigned to the directory:

```
#lsattr /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/
------------- /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp/afile
```

I changed the shell (temporarily) of the apache user to bash, logged into the shell and was able to write to the directory.

Selinux is disabled.

fixweb has been run.

I created two scripts, tmp.cfm and tmp.php, which simply attempted to write a file in the target directory, browsed to the tmp scripts in the browser and both were unable to write to the directory.

I also created an alias to the directory in apache:

```
Alias /atemp /target-dir
<Location /atemp>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

Restarted apache and was still unable to get access to this directory.

I've seen a similar permission issue when working with Wordpress.

I suspect that this is something to do with my apache binary but I haven't heard back from the providers of that binary, so I was hoping to get some assistance from a larger audience.

---

**Edit:** I'd be open to other possible problems that would cause this that I haven't considered.

Comment: Do you have any <Directory "/opt/coldfusion9/runtime/servers/coldfusion/SERVER-INF/temp/wwwroot-tmp"> (or a parent directory thereof) that might be granting or removing access?

Comment: No. Double checked to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an Adobe ColdFusion 9 issue after all.